# move_base goal_tolerance has no effect

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up the navigation stack and was experimenting with the goal_tolerance parameters. I set the following in my launch file:
xy_goal_tolerance: 300.0
yaw_goal_tolerance: 300.0
free_goal_vel: True

When I set a 2D Nav Goal with a couple of meters distance to the current 2D Pose in rviz I get the status: "This goal has been accepted by the simple action server"

Only when I set the goal exactly onto the current 2D Pose I get the result "Goal reached." How come, the tolerance parameters seem to be ignored?
Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401631/move_base-goal_tolerance-has-no-effect/) by [phixxx6](https://answers.ros.org/users/106410/phixxx6/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was a rather silly one. I did not configure move_base to actually use the local_planner for which I was setting the goal_tolerance parameter. Instead I was using the default local_planner.

---

Originally posted by [phixxx6](https://answers.ros.org/users/106410/phixxx6/) with karma: 16 on 2022-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0